# How to compile PHP 5.3 CGI?

Tags: php5, cgi

php-cgi seems to have vanished in PHP 5.3.1. I've tried both the --enable-cgi and --disable-cli flags for ./configure, but it doesn't create a binary under the sapi/cgi subdirectory.

Comment: Which OS and what version of OS are you using ?

Comment: RHEL4. (why is the a 15-character minimum on this comment box?!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realise I'm very late to the party on this, but I think PHP FPM (FastCGI Process Manager) is the replacement.

You need to use PHP 5.3.3 and use the `--enable-fpm` configure flag, or use the patch at the [php-fpm](http://php-fpm.org/) website for earlier versions. An executable called php-fpm gets created in sapi/fpm.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that php-fpm and php-cgi are mutually exclusive -- that is, if you use the `--enable-fpm` configure option, it will not build the php-cgi executable.

If you need both present, a workaround is to build without `--enable-fpm`, store away a copy of the `php-cgi` executable, re-configure with `--enable-fpm`, and re-build.

Answer (score 2):

I solved same problem.

Looks like when you try to `./configure` you use `--with-apxs` -that block to compile php-cgi version. Simply not set this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu I can see that the application is named as "php5-cgi"

Comment: No, I am using RHEL4 (which does not have a PHP5 RPM) and need to compile from source.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following switches for ./configure, however this is for CentOS 5 and PHP 5.2.13, I hope this helps in some way:

```
./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_BASE \
  --with-config-file-path=$INSTALL_BASE/etc/ \
  --enable-force-cgi-redirect \
  --enable-mbstring \
  --enable-fastcgi \
  --enable-gd-native-ttf \
  --enable-ftp \
  --enable-sockets \
  --enable-wddx \
  --enable-sqlite-utf8 \
  --enable-mbstring \
  --enable-mbregex \
  --enable-calendar \
  --enable-zip \
  --with-libxml-dir=$INSTALL_BASE \
  --with-freetype-dir=$INSTALL_BASE \
  --with-openssl \
  --with-mhash=$INSTALL_BASE \
  --with-mcrypt=$INSTALL_BASE \
  --with-zlib-dir=$INSTALL_BASE \
  --with-bz2 \
  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
  --with-png-dir=/usr \
  --with-gd \
  --with-iconv=$INSTALL_BASE \
  --with-curl=$INSTALL_BASE \
  --with-pgsql \
  --with-gettext \
  --with-imap=$INSTALL_BASE \
  --with-imap-ssl=/usr \
  --enable-bcmath \
  --with-pear \
  --with-xmlrpc
```